# Manipulating a table in SQL so that each row assumes the data for the one after it

Tags: mysql, sql, rows, screen-scraping

I've had a script screen scrape a whole lot of data for me into a table. In my case, I've scraped a bunch of story arcs and their respective chapters from a manga. When verifying the integrity of the data in the table, I found that my script had a hiccup and the chapters are now consistently showing the chapters for the story arc in the row in front of them.

The data in the column on the left matches the data on the right but down a row.

[image]

I'm wondering if there's a way to "shift" each row in the column so that it assumes the data in front of it at a certain point.

Comment: Do the numbers in the first column increase by 1 each row for all your data?

Comment: Yeah it has auto_increment applied to the primary key